# Rise function (Gomp)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

I am a biologist trying to understand the ODE of growth tumour:

Let $N(t)$ denote the number of cancerous cells at time $t$, which are proliferating at a rate form

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=\frac{\lambda N}{\alpha}\left[1-\left(\frac{N}{\theta}\right)^{\alpha}\right] ... (1)$$

where $\alpha(\geq 0 )$ and $\theta(\geq 0 )$ are determined from the growth characteristics of the tumour.

and then it says that the solution to this equation is:

$$ N(t) = N_0 \{ \left[ \frac{N_0}{\theta} \right]^{\alpha} + e^{\lambda t} \left( 1-\left[ \frac{N_0}{\theta}\right]^{\alpha}\right)  \}^{-1/\alpha} ...(2)$$

where $N_0 = N(t=0)$.

I still don`t understand how you get this answer, I tried to do the simple form, i.e, solving the Gompertzian growth rate,
$$\frac{dN}{dt}= -\lambda N \ ln \left( \frac{N}{\theta}\right) $$, I solved this using the method of separable variables and with some help hehe

My first question is: How can you generalised Gompertzian growth into (1) ? It is not clear for me how you can get (2)?

And then the paper at some point consider now the effect of exposing a tumour cell population to a cycle-nonspecific  drug at concentration $C(t)$, thus it gets a new generalised equation:

$$ \frac{1}{N} \ \frac{dN}{dt} = \begin{cases}
 \lambda - \mu C(t), \ N \leq N_c,\\
\lambda + \frac{\lambda_1}{\alpha} \left[1- \left(\frac{N}{N_c}\right)^{\alpha}\right]- \mu C(t) , \ N \geq N_c
\end{cases}$$

Here my question is why is the meaning of the cases in the paper, for example, biologically talking, what does it mean considering the case $N_0 \geq N_c \lambda - \mu C_0 \geq 0$?

This is the paper: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82695656.pdf

Really, I would appreciate your hints, help, comments to understand this paper. Thank you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Look into Bernoulli DE and their solution methods, this gives the solution of your equation in a few lines.

Comment: Do you mean this  Bernoulli DE? $y'+p(x)y = q(x)y^n$ ? Sorry I googled it, still new for me hehe I can't see the similitudes to $\frac{dN}{dt}=\frac{\lambda N}{\alpha}\left[1-\left(\frac{N}{\theta}\right)^{\alpha}\right]$

Comment: You get $p(x)=-\fracλα$, $q(x)=-\frac{λ}{αθ^α}$ and $n=α+1$. Or just compute the derivative of $u(x)=θ^αN(x)^{-α}$ and insert the ODE.

Comment: Quick question, why if $\alpha. \rightarrow 0 $, then (1) transforms in: $ \frac{dN}{dt} = - \lambda N ln (\frac{\lambda}{\theta} )$. I mean if $\alpha. \rightarrow 0$, then from $\frac{dN}{dt}=\frac{\lambda N}{\alpha}\left[1-\left(\frac{N}{\theta}\right)^{\alpha}\right] $, we have that $\frac{\lambda N}{\alpha} \rightarrow \infty$ and $\left[1-\left(\frac{N}{\theta}\right)^{\alpha}\right] \rightarrow 1$ since $\left(\frac{N}{\theta}\right)^{\alpha}$ approaches to $1$ when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ , right? or Am I wrong ? It is not clear why you get Gompertz funct if $\alpha \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Yes, that is indeed one of the definitions of the logarithm, $\ln(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(x^{1/n}-1)$. You could also say that $\frac{x^α-1}{α-0}$ is a difference quotient and its limit is the derivative of $x^α=e^{α\ln x}$ by $α$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $u(t)=N(t)^{-α}$. Then the derivative of this is
$$
u'(t)=-αN(t)^{-α-1}N'(t)=-λ[N(t)^{-α}−θ^{-α}]=-λ[u(t)-θ^{-α}].\tag1
$$
This now is a linear equation, and additionally separable, giving the solution
$$
u(t)-θ^{-α}=[u(0)-θ^{-α}]e^{-λt}.\tag2
$$
Now replace $u$ for $N$ to get
\begin{align}
(N(t)/θ)^{-α} &= 1+[(N(0)/θ)^{-α}-1]e^{-λt}=(N(0)/θ)^{-α}\left((N(0)/θ)^{α}+[1-(N(0)/θ)^{α}]e^{-λt}\right),\tag3
\\~\\
N(t) &= \frac{N(0)}{[(N(0)/θ)^{α}(1-e^{-λt})+e^{-λt}]^{1/α}}.\tag4
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry but, is it true that $\frac{dN}{dt}= -\lambda N \ ln \left( \frac{N}{\theta}\right)$ is equivalent to $\frac{dN}{dt}= \lambda N \ ln \left( \frac{\theta}{N}\right)$, to me this is true because of the derivative of $\frac{d(ln(N))}{dt}$

Comment: @Rachel : Yes, $-\ln(x)=\ln(\frac1x)$ is true. In general $\ln(x^c)=c\ln(x)$.

Comment: thank you very much, and sorry I am so slow learning this new stuff hehe I just solved the Gompertz function and got that $N(t) = \theta \left( \frac{N_0}{\theta}\right)^{(e^{-\lambda\theta t})}$ is my solution, is it right?

Comment: and constant solution when $N=\theta$

Comment: In the solution that yo gave, the $N(t) = \frac{N(0)}{[(N(0)/θ)^{α}(1-e^{-λt})+e^{-λt}]^{-α}}$ the $-\alpha$ is $-\frac{1}{\alpha}$, right? and sorry but how did you get the numerator $N_0$ to be alone there?

Comment: You are right, the exponent has to be $1/α$. It is often useful to extract the initial value if the remaining terms are simple and so that they give the value $1$ at the initial point. This automatically gives the correct solution branch.

Comment: Do you know literature to solve $$ \frac{1}{N} \ \frac{dN}{dt} = \begin{cases}
 \lambda - \mu C(t), \ N \leq N_c,\\
\lambda + \frac{\lambda_1}{\alpha} \left[1- \left(\frac{N}{N_c}\right)^{\alpha}\right]- \mu C(t) , \ N \geq N_c
\end{cases}$$, I was reading that maybe using numerical methods but I am not sure. Do you have some hints to solve this ?

Comment: You can again substitute $u=N^α$ or $u=N^{-α}$ to eliminate the power. In the second case you get again linear ODE that you can treat with an integrating factor. However, the term $C(t)$ will require numerical quadrature or numerical integration, so that you can also do that from the start, depending on what type of results you want to get.

Comment: Sorry again, what does it mean that in the Gompertz growth model, $N_c$ corresponds to the tumour cell number at which transition between the two phases of growth occurs ? I don't understand this $N_c$ definition as a "transition between the two phases of growth occurs" mathematically speaking, and biologically speaking is this transition possible?